# Reading in from file in Ruby with while-loop

Tags: ruby, file-io, while-loop

I've found the following bit of code used frequently when you want to read in a file line-by-line in Ruby:

```
while (line = fileobject.gets)
  # code block such as 'puts line' or something
end
```

I just need some help understanding what is going on there.  I know that 'while' is to be followed by a boolean expression, and then the code block will be repeated until the expression returns 'false'.

So here, the boolean expression is `line = fileobject.gets`...but how is that evaluated as true or false?  To me it looks like an assignment statement, that is, you're assigning 'line' to be whatever the next line of the fileobject is.

I understand that this WILL work for reading in from text files line by line, but I'm not comfortable using it until I know WHY it works.  Maybe I'm just too used to C++ with its counters and incrementing.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The first principle that will help you understand this is that in Ruby, conditions aren't expected to be just true or false, they can be any value. The value is then considered 'truthy' or 'falsey' - that is - like being true of like being false. In Ruby, there are only two values that are falsey (act like false): [`false` itself and `nil`](https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362#whats-truthy-and-falsey-in-ruby).

So for example:

```
if nil  # nil is 'falsey'
  # Won't go here!
else
  # Will go here!
end

if 'randomstring'   # any string is 'truthy'
  # will go here!
end
```

This idea applies the same way to while loops.

Next up is the [`gets` method.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-gets) If you check out the documentation, you can see that the `IO::gets` method returns `nil` when it reaches the end of the file. So, when that happens, `line` is set to `nil`, which is a fasley value, and the loop exits.

---

Short version: `nil` is like `false` and `gets` returns `nil` when it reaches the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

### The Analysis

> while (line = fileobject.gets); end

This isn't really idiomatic Ruby; it's more of a Perl-ish way of doing things, although it certainly works. The *reason* it works is that almost everything in Ruby is an expression that returns some sort of value. For example:

```
# Open some file for reading.
fileobject = File.open '/etc/passwd'

# As long as File#gets evaluates as truthy, keep going.
while line = fileobject.gets
  puts line
end
```

The "magic" here is that the expression `line = fileobject.gets` returns nil when it reaches EOF, and so the while condition evaluates as falsey. Until then, every time `fileobject.gets` returns a string the expression evaluates as truthy, so the while-loop just keeps chugging along and assigning successive lines to your *line* variable. See [IO#gets](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-gets) for more on this useful method.

### A Better Way with File Objects

A more idiomatic way to do this would be to do this in a self-closing block. for example:

```
File.open '/etc/passwd' do |file|
  file.each_line { |line| puts line }
end
```

Self-closing blocks are (possibly) just as "magical" as while-loops that leverage the truthiness of IO#gets, but it certainly seems clearer and more Ruby-like than the original code sample. YMMV.

### Even More Compact Using IO Objects

As [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25298482/1301972) reminded me, the following is also very idiomatic in Ruby:

```
IO.foreach('/etc/passwd') { |line| puts line }
```

This leverages [IO::foreach](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-foreach) to implicitly open the named file, pass each line through the block for processing, and then closing the file automatically when the block ends. It is very similar to the previous example above, but has the advantage of being shorter and (in some cases) semantically clearer. Whether or not the implicit file handling is too "magical" or not for your taste, it's definitely worth knowing this particular construct too.

Answer (score 1):

> I've found the following bit of code used frequently when you want to
>   read in a file line-by-line

I don't know what articles you've been reading, but no well grounded rubyist would ever read a file like that.  Instead they would do something like this:

```
IO.foreach('data1.txt') do |line|
  print line
end
```

As for this:

```
line = fileobject.gets
```

In order for ruby to execute that assignment, ruby has to first execute `fileobject.gets`.  And `fileobject.gets` either returns a string or nil(when end of file is reached).  And any string is considered true in ruby--even blank strings.  For example:

```
str = ""

if str
  puts "true"
else
  puts "false"
end

--output:--
true
```

So the code:

```
line = fileobject.gets
```

is equivalent to:

```
line = "some string"
```

or

```
line = nil
```

Finally, an assignment returns the right hand side, so you are left with:

```
while "some string"
```

or

```
while nil
```

and ruby evaluates `while "some string"` as  `while true`; and ruby evaluates `while nil` as `while false` because in ruby only nil and false are false in a boolean context, e.g. in an if or while conditional.

Comment: Thanks!  That bit of code in my question is actually from a book I'm reading on beginning Ruby; I'm sure there are better ways to do it but the author probably just used that as a simple example.

Comment: Nice. I always forget about [IO::foreach](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-foreach) as a more compact alternative with an implicit open.